# How to create fractions in any font?

Tags: windows, graphics, fonts

My window application uses a lot of fraction values like `5/16, 5/32, 1/8` etc. to print in the reports. My application is using `Times Fraction` font which has all these fractions. But now when I am changing the font to `Verdana`, all these fractions are distorted as `Verdana` does not support all these fractions. It only supports 3 fraction values: `1/2, 1/4 and 3/4.`

My question is, how can I make other fraction values like `5/16, 5/32, 1/8` etc. in `Verdana`?

Comment: Probably you can't. Maybe rendering your items in mixed fonts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typographic (especially those with heavy scientific and mathematical use like [TeX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TeX)) systems do this by combining reduced size digits with a faction slash  (U+2044) (or the normal slash, if the more specific glyph is not available (U+002F "solidus" aka. virgule).

You'll also need to specifically position the digits with vertical and horizontal offsets (including allowing for the variable with if the typeface has proportional digits) and even a little negative space around the slash to kern it.

If you just need a few fractions to display, I would suggest putting this in the nice to have bucket and sticking to "123/456" until more important requirements are done.